# Raspberry + socket.io works on local network but not from outside

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi serving an html page through a server.js file. The main lines (not all the code) are:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
...
app.listen(8000);
...
fucntion handler(req,res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname+'/../index.html' function(err,data) {
...
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  setInterval(function(){
  ...
  socket.emit('tempUpd',date,temp);
}, 2000);
});
```

On the index.html:

```
<head>
...
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
<div id="info"></div>
---
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.6:8000');

socket.on('tempUpd', function(date, temp){
   document.getElementById("info").textContent = temp;
});
...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the idea is to update a temperature measurement every 2 seconds.

When I connect from my smartphone to my Raspberry PI through the local network (using wireless), everything works as expected and I can access the webpage and see the temperature values changing every 2 seconds.

When I turn off the wireless on the smartphone and connect to the Raspberry through the mobile network (having configured my router to allow the connection to pass to the raspberry pi), I can see the webpage, but all the information passed through the socket is never displayed.

Thinking that for some reason I wasn't able to see dynamic elements on that page, I added another , and added some code so that it showed current time every 2 seconds with setInterval. I see time changing, but nothing that comes through the socket gets displayed. Again, I switch to the local network, and everything is visible, including the info passed through the socket.

Any idea on what might be happening?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`192.168.1.6` is a local network address.  You can't access that address from outside your local network.  The mobile network is outside your local network.  When you use WiFi from your phone, you are connecting to the access point inside your local network and you can then route to `192.168.1.6`.

To access it from the public mobile network (from outside your own local network), you would have to have a public IP address that was routed to your server from outside your local network.

A common way to solve this is to get a public IP address (or use dynamic DNS for DHCP assigned addresses) for your internet connection and then configure "port forwarding" on your internet router.  This will take incoming packets destined for a particular port on your public IP address and forward them to a specific device (e.g. your Raspberry Pi) on your internal network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isn't the 192.168.1.6 address only used to communicate between the server.js and the index.html? And being both on the same machine, shouldn't it work?

Comment: @FilipeSim - That address is used to communicate from browser to server and will need to be resolved from whatever network the browser is on.  The 192.168.x.x address is what is known as a private address (not for use on public networks).  See [Private Neworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) for more info.

Comment: @FilipeSim - perhaps this might help.  The `index.html` file may be hosted on the server, but it is downloaded by the browser and then is actually executed in the browser.  Thus, when it tries to connect to the server, it must be able to do that from the network the browser is on to the server.

Comment: @FilipeSim - Since it appears you may be new here, do you know that if you get your question answered, then you can select the best answer by click the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn both you and the person that provided the answer some reputation points on the site here for following the correct procedure.

Comment: I am (really) new! :) Not only at stackoverflow, but also to programming using network technologies. Thank you very much for your answer. Now that I think of it, I feel dumb. There are a lot of code examples out there but few explain the mechanics that happen behind the scenes. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @FilipeSim - You dive in, try stuff and learn how it all works.  FYI, I have a raspberry Pi running a node.js server on my home network.  Mine is in my attic, sampling temperature probes every 10 seconds and switching attic fans based on differential temperatures.  It also has a web interface for controlling, configuring and monitoring it.  I did not go to the trouble of making it accessible from outside the home network as there was marginal benefit to doing that (other than showing people from my phone when away from the home) and I'd have to do a lot of security work to secure it.

Comment: That is in a way similar to what I want to do. Sample some sensors and have some actuators, everything under a web interface. I do want to have it accessible from my smartphone. I am now a little worried since from your words it seems there's a lot to be done in terms of security. I thought that it just meant doing a port redirection to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @FilipeSim - you can just port forward and if all your web server does is "view" (e.g. can't change anything), then maybe you're good.  But, if you can configure anything, upload anything, change anything, etc..., then you have to make sure that only an authorized user can do that with some form of authentication.  And, will have to make sure your Pi/Node server are kept up-to-date vs. any security vulnerabilities discovered in the future.

Comment: I was thinking on having a web interface with some controls to turn on and off some relays and other simple actuators. Now that you mention the safety issues, I guess it isn't a clever protection to rely on (theoretically) being the only one to know the IP of the Raspberry automation server :)

Comment: @FilipeSim - The IP you would access would be the public IP of your home internet connection which would be forwarded to the private IP on your network of the Raspberry Pi.  Your public IP is findable by IP range scanners (which is one reason why you need a firewall on your internet connection) so relying on nobody finding that you have an active web server there would not be smart.  You'd have to implement authentication.  Perfectly doable, but extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the index.html page to open your socket dynamically, based on the ip address of the node server.  As others have pointed out, when you are connecting to the server from the internet, your Pi isn't at 192.168.1.6. (that's your local network)

If you are able to hit the web page then you have your router is forwarding things correctly.

On you index.html page, change the line from:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.6:8000');
```

to:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.host + ':8000');
```

Also make sure you are forwarding port 8000 on your router to your Pi as well.

Good luck.

--Ed